# swift custom .framework cannot find protocol

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

I have this framework `XXUIKit.framework` in within that i have a protocol defined as `XXConfigurable.swift`

```
@objc(XXUIConfigurable)
protocol XXUIConfigurable {
 func configureItem(indexPath: NSIndexPath, data:AnyObject);
}
```

The Classes internal to the framework can find this protocol just fine. Just when I attempt to use it outside of the framework:

```
import XXUIKit
...
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: sections[indexPath.row].cell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? XXUIConfigurable
    return header
}
```

it cannot find the type:

```
error: use of undeclared type 'XXUIConfigurable'
```

the main app can find and use  other classes from `XXUIKIt.framework`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh, apologies but I worked it out.

`public protocol XXUIConfigurable`